# Get data from cutom table using query

Tags: magento2

I have tried to load collection in custom grid Based on current product data

```php
<?php
$redirectUrl = $this->helper->getCurrentProduct();
             $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
            $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
            $param = $request->getParams();
            $productId =  $param['current_id'];
             $product = $this->helper->getLoadProduct($productId);
             $sku = $product->getSku();
             $TestData = $product->getTestData();
             $TestDatasarr = explode("|", $TestData);
             $TestDatavalues = "'" . implode("', '", $TestDatasarr) . "'";
            $this->getSelect()->orwhere("main_table.testdatas IN($TestDatavalues)");
```

In the above code i got `$TestDatavalues` like `'test','test1','test2'` when I pass the values manually in getslect in like `$this->getSelect()->orwhere("main_table.testdatas IN('test','test1','test2')");`

It shows the collection data but when I pass the variable it shows empty data `$this->getSelect()->orwhere("main_table.testdatas IN($TestDatavalues)");` when i print it shows the empty

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: Can anyone help on this

Answer (score 0):

You should use the code below:

```
$this->getSelect()->orwhere("main_table.testdatas IN(?)", $TestDatavalues);
```

Comment: I have tried again it shows empty data

Comment: If i pass the values in manually it shows data but i am also get the value from $TestDatavalues  while pass in variable it shows empty

Comment: if i print query 
 $test = $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.testdatas IN($TestDatavalues)")->__toString();
        var_dump($test);
It shows the query of the output perfect when run the same in phpmyadmin but in grid it does not shows the data

Comment: Can anyone help me on this tried lot of methods